# Hint / warning is not completely displayed when asking a Question

Tags: bug, design

I just saw that a part of the warning (question appears subjective...), when asking a question, is hidden because the div is to small.
I have the resolution 1920x1080, maybe for other resolutions it looks better.

[image]

EDIT:

I saw now that just multiple notifications over each other.
So if the message on the top is smaller than the one behind, it looks like some letters are cutted.

[image]

Comment: Can confirm I get the same issue.